# Combinatorial Meaning of the Binomial Coefficient $s\choose k$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I am wondering if there is a combinatorial meaning of the binomial coefficient $s\choose k$, which is defined as $${s\choose k}=\frac{s(s-1)(s-2)\cdots(s-k+1)}{k!},$$
where $s$ is a real number and $k$ is a natural number. If $s$ is a natural number which is at least $k$, there is an obvious combinatorial meaning of $s\choose k$. Am wondering the general case where $s$ is a real number. Does $s\choose k$ still have any combinatorial meaning at all?

Comment: Combinatorics deals with distinct objects, so it is unlikely to have one

Comment: That depends on exactly what you mean by "combinatorial meaning"....

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I was wondering if there is any interpretation of the expression $s\choose k$ which is an analogue to the usual combinatorial meaning for the case that $s$ being an natural number.

Comment: Well, if $s$ is a negative integer, then $\binom{s}k=(-1)^k\binom{s+k-1}k$ is (up to a sign) equal to the number of ways to choose a size $k$ multiset from a set of $|s|$ objects.

Comment: Thanks @MikeEarnest! Does $s\choose k$ have any other meaning at all if $s$ is not an integer?

Comment: $\dbinom{-1/2}{k} = \left(-1/4\right)^k \dbinom{2k}{k}$ is a known formula. Outside of that, I don't recall seeing $\dbinom{s}{n}$ for non-integer $s$ in combinatorics very often.